# Shorten directory name on Powerlevel10k

Tags: zsh

I just installed Powerlevel10k, and I got to say that I am really liking it. However, I would like to **shorten the name of the *current directory* module to the current folder**.

In a few words, I want to change this:

```
~/Documents/Repositories/cool-project
```

To just this:

```
~ cool-project
```

While researching a solution to this problem, I came across these settings:

```
  # If directory is too long, shorten some of its segments to the shortest possible unique
  # prefix. The shortened directory can be tab-completed to the original.
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY=truncate_to_unique
```

I suspect modifying this setting is key to achieve what I desire, but I do not know what alternative settings there are for `SHORTEN_STRATEGY` because I do not seem to find documentation or a styling syntax anywhere.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176257/customizing-powerleve10k-prompt) you can achieve that by changing `truncate_to_unique` to `truncate_to_last`.

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you :)

Comment: You're very welcome.